# Grails: getting old instance after persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, session, grails

I'm facing a weird issue in Grails. When I make a `findBy` call after changing and saving values of a domain, I am still getting the old values even after the values get persisted to the database. I can see the values are changed in my table.

My code is something like this:

```
Car car = Car.findByCarId(carId)
car.modelName = "some_model_name"
car.save() // Not flushing here
Tire tire = Tire.findByIdAndCarId(tireId,carId)
tire.manufacturer = "some_manufacturer"
tire.save()
Light light = Light.findByIdAndCarId(lightId,carId)
light.manufacturer = "some_manufacturer"
light.save()
Mirror mirror = Mirror.findByIdAndCarId(mirrorId,carId)
mirror.manufacturer = "some_manufacturer"
mirror.save()
```

My domain also has a few one-to-many associations. Let's say something like this:

```
class Car {
    String modelName
    static hasMany = [tires : Tire, mirrors : Mirror, lights : Light]
}
```

After these changes, when I make a DB call for the `Car` domain, I still get the older values:

```
Car car = Car.findById(carId) 
println car.modelName // This gives older value
```

I know this is because the values are yet to be persisted to the database. I want to know if I use `car.save(flush: true)` in the above code, will it cause `collection was not processed by flush()` error? However, I am also getting the older values even after the values are persisted to the database. (e.g. when I make the above query after a long time) I can see the values are changed in my tables, but when I do the above query, it gives me the old values. Does Hibernate cache this query automatically? I use the above query quite a lot of times.

When I use `withNewSession`, it retrieves the new values:

```
Car car
Car.withNewSession {
    car = Car.findById(carId,[readOnly : true])
}
println car.modelName // Gives new value
```

I want to know how this is giving the new values everytime, since I'm not flushing the current session. Instead, I'm only using a new Hibernate session. Does `readOnly` command flush the current session? The above code works fine for me. Should I use `withNewSession` instead of flushing while saving?

Thanks.

Comment: where are you changing those objects ? controller ? service ? is it the service transactional ?

Comment: I'm changing it in controller

Comment: You have to do all your staff into a service layer, cause all services are transactional, if you are not doing that, you are using grails in a bad way

Comment: I do most of it inside service. This is something small where I don't want to create a new service for

Answer (score 0):

All your business logic has to be inside a transactional service. All services in grails are transactional by default. Take care about notations as `@Transactional` or `@NotTransactional`

If you want to manage data in a controller (not recommended) you should surround your code into a Transaction. An allow hibernate to manage the transaction, not breaking it with flush.

All changes are commited after a transaction finishes.

Remember that you could also use the refresh method which re-reads the state of the given instance from the underlying database.

```
domainInstance.refresh()
```